# Sum chars and subtract to get file

Tags: c++, char, fopen

I'm making a program to sum a char from a file with a random number and then subtract to get the file again.

The problem is when I sum them and subtract, the resulting file is not the same.

Can be bad math mine or something I don't know about chars.

Code to sum (edited):

```
while (!feof(filename))
{
    size_t read = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), max_array, filename);
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < read; i++)
    {
        unsigned char rdn = GetRandom_Soft();
        /*
        if (buf[i] + rdn > 255) buf[i] = (buf[i] + rdn) - 255;
        else buf[i] = buf[i] + rdn;
        */
        buf[i] = buf[i] + rdn;
        num[i] = rdn;
    }
    fwrite(&num, sizeof(char), read, filename_n);
    fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), read, filename2);
}
```

Code `GetRandom()` (edited):

```
int GetRandom_Soft()
{
    return rand() % 256;
}
```

Code to subtract (edited):

```
while (!feof(filename2))
{
    size_t read_c = fread(&num, sizeof(char), max_array, filename_n);
    fread(&buf, sizeof(char), max_array, filename2);
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < read_c; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] - num[i];
        /*
        if(buf[i] - num[i] < 0) buf[i] = (buf[i] - num[i]) +255;
        else buf[i] = buf[i] - num[i];
        */
    }
    fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), read_c, filename);
}
```

*********Update 1*********

`filename` = File pointer to the original file

`filename_n` = File pointer to the file with the numbers

`filename2` = File pointer to the file with the sum of `filename` and `filename_n`

********Update 2(edited)*********

Declaration of chars array:

`int num[9999]`

`int buf[9999]`

`int rdn[9999]`

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the info

Comment: @MichaelWalz Because I'm working in a C/C++ project.

Comment: Have you look at filename content, what is `num`, `buf` ?

Comment: Do you open file in binary mode ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I looked and it's correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I am

Comment: What's `filename`, `filename_n`, and `filename2`?

Comment: There is no such thing called C/C++. If you are using a C++ compiler, you are using C++. Although your code snippet looks much more like C

Comment: @PasserBy Sorry when I say C/C++, I  really mean with a C++ program but that part only use C.

Comment: @Samega7Cattac you should post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetRandom_Soft()` returns `char`, whose value range is [-128;127], and you try to assign values from the range [0 ; 255] - not gonna work properly.

I also suspect that you're doing similar things here:

```
buf[i] = buf[i] + rdn;
```

and here:

```
buf[i] = buf[i] - num[i];
```

I suspect that either `buf` or `num` or both are of different types than `char*` (e.g. `unsigned char*`) **AND/OR**  the result of the addition or the subtraction is outside of the `char` value range which corrupts the result.

**EDIT**

After your update it's almost certainly the problem with `unsigned char` overflow. `unsigned char` takes value from range [0;255] - if the result of your addition is > 255 or the result of your subtraction is < 0, than you're going to get erroneous results. It seems that interpreting the values as `int` makes much more sense in case of your numbers.

Comment: Good to know that! but I try to add `unsigned` to the chars declaration and that don't solve the problem, but is more logic to have it, so I add it and updated the question.

Comment: And of corse add 255 if subtraction < 0

Comment: If you keep using unsigned char, you won't be able to detect that sum < 0 or sum > 255. The result is going is converted to unsigned char, so it's goint to still be in range [0;255]. Read this topic to get a better understanding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530358/how-256-stored-in-char-variable-and-unsigned-char

Just use ints and you won't have to worry about your value range unless your numbers are huge.

Comment: so I can't use `unsigned char` for any of char declarations, right? Is better to use int?

Comment: Ok, using `int` instead of `unsigned char` almost worked, I can now see some part with the original chars, but few

Comment: I recognized some char in the file, but never mind already solved, later I will post my answer but this answer will be marked as response because of the link you posted I find out whats wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148791/discussion-between-kjmag-and-samega-7cattac).